# How to close a dropdown with JS with a second click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the functionality that allows you to open and close the hidden dropdown that you can see in the link but I want to also be able to close the already open dropdown if you click the same image again.

At the moment I can only close the ones on the outside of the clicked element.

Main fragment of code (wired up on ready), complete working sample  - [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/960cm7ux/):

```
function close() {
    $('.slide').removeClass("active");
    $('.slide').css("padding-bottom", 0 + "px");
} 

function open() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).css("padding-bottom", height);
} 

$('.slide').on('touchstart click', function() {

    close();

    if ( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
        close();
    } 

    if ( !$(this).hasClass("active") ) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).css("padding-bottom", height);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="slide"> title 
      <div class="js-slide">content of slide  hidden via CSS when 
        "active" class is not present</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/960cm7ux/

Comment: not allowing me to add this link for some reason, sorry I've added it here

Comment: Inlined sample... removed thank you note...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change to your code seems to achieve the desired effect:

```
$('.slide').on('touchstart click', function() {

    if ( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
        close();
    } else {
        close();
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).css("padding-bottom", height);
    }
});
```

Because your `close()` function removes the `active` class from the element, you need to have it in a place where it won't mess with the conditions your checking around the `active` class. Moving it inside the `if` blocks is an easy and quick change to fix the issue. Some people might be bothered by the way `close()` is repeated in both blocks. If you're one of those people, refactor appropriately. Just don't do the obvious-seeming move `close()` outside the `if`/`then` because that will cause this issue to re-appear.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/960cm7ux/1/

Comment: ah awesommeee... i get it.. so basically what i was doing is always ending up with an open dropdown.. where as this closes  it unless it doesn't have the class active..